# Spring Boot fat jar renaming

Tags: spring-boot

When I try to rename the jar file generated on build Spring does not generate a fat jar anymore:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
    baseName = 'app'
    classifier = null
    version = null
}
```

I will see the `app.jar` in my `/build/libs/` folder but it only contains the project not the dependencies and no other files are generated. How can I make Spring rename the jar it generates which includes the dependencies?

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.5.9.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the classifier on the `jar` task to `null` rather than the default of an empty string (`""`). Unless you explicitly configure `bootRepackage` to apply to a `jar` task, tasks with a non-default classifier are ignored. This is hinted at in the info-level logging of `bootRepackage`:

```
Jar task not repackaged (didn't match withJarTask): task ':jar'
```

The simplest thing to do is to leave the `classifier` with its default empty string value. This would leave your `jar` task with the following configuration:

```
jar {
    baseName = 'app'
    version = null
}
```

When `bootRepackage` runs, the `app.jar` file produced by the `jar` task will then be repackaged and contain its dependencies as you require.